Push/pop animation of NavigationView not work when nested in TabView.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
I have this sample code:
@main
struct SwiftUITestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            VStack {
                TabView {
                    HomeView()
                }
                .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            }
            CustomTabBarView()
        }
    }
}

struct CustomTabBarView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("CUSTOM TABBAR GO HERE")
    }
}

struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: HomeDetailView()) {
                    Text("GO TO ORANGE")
                }
            }
            .background(.red)
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}

struct HomeDetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.orange)
    }
}

I want to use my own custom tab bar UI. My intention is in every tab, I have a NavigationView of their own. Because I want to support iOS 15 so I have to use NavigationView. When launch app, the UI work as expected but when I navigate to other screen using NavigationLink, there is no animation.

I'm expecting to have animation for push/pop in NavigationView. Any insights or suggestions would be appreciated!

Is the reason for using .page tab view style, so that you can swipe between pages? If not, then the animation problem can be fixed by removing this modifier and hiding the tab bar. Btw, did you intend that the custom tab bar should be inside the VStack?

I did not intend to have custom tab bar inside VStack.  I'm using .page just to remove default tabbar, actually I don't want user can swipe between pages either

Sounds like you don't need to be using a TabView at all - just use a ZStack instead. Also, the VStack can be removed if you did not intend to put the custom tab bar inside it. You will then be letting the WindowGroup lay out the main content and the toolbar in whatever way it chooses.

So then I have to if else or switch statement to switch between tabs? I try that but they have a downside is when I change tab the old view got be destroy, not like when using TabView when View is preserve when changing tab

Also I want my custom tab bar to be at bottom of the screen

So you are assuming that since the custom tab bar appears last, it will be shown at the bottom of the screen? It might work that way. But I would put it inside a VStack to be sure. In fact, I would put it inside the VStack that you already have. You might want to add (spacing: 0) to the VStack too.

Yes, that's why I put my custom tab bar inside VStack

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types

@BenzyNeez From your suggestion, I'm organizing my tab using ZStack on change zIndex to show current selected tab. However, there is a problem is all of my subviews onAppear get called when app launch, I want behavior app TabView whenever a tab is selected, onAppear get called. How can I acheive that behavior with ZStack?

@duckSern1108 That sounds like the topic for a new question.

You don't need to use .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never)) modifier to achieve this, you can do this by binding the selectedTab with TabView.
struct ContentView: View {

  @State var selectedTab = 0

  var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            HomeView(page: 0)
                .tag(0)
            
            HomeView(page: 1)
                .tag(1)
            
            HomeView(page: 2)
                .tag(2)
            
            HomeView(page: 3)
                .tag(3)
            
            HomeView(page: 4)
                .tag(4)
        }
        
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
            .frame(width: 350, height: 70)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .shadow(radius: 0.8)

        HStack {
            ForEach(0..<5, id: \.self) { index in
                    Button {
                        selectedTab = index
                    } label: {
                        CustomTabItem(imageName: "cross", title: "Item \(index)", isActive: (selectedTab == index))
                    }
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 30)
        .frame(height: 70)
    }
  }

  @ViewBuilder func CustomTabItem(imageName: String, title: String, isActive: Bool) -> some View{
    VStack(alignment: .center) {
        HStack(alignment: .center) {
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: imageName)
                .resizable()
                .renderingMode(.template)
                .foregroundColor(isActive ? .purple : .gray)
                .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
            Spacer()
        }
        Text(title)
            .foregroundColor(isActive ? .purple : .gray)
    }
  }
}

struct HomeView: View {

  var page: Int

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: HomeDetailView()) {
                Text("Tab \(page) is selected")
            }
        }
        .background(.red)
    }
    .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
  }
}

struct HomeDetailView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Rectangle()
        .fill(.orange)
  }
}



When running your code, when I navigate to HomeDetailView there is a white area at bottom actually an UITabBar when I debug UI
